# What are recommended angles for different wood-turning tools

Tags: wood, sharpening, turning

I am going to make a jig for sharpening my lathe tools and I want to mark on the jig where each tool should be sharpened to. Like the roughing gouge to the skew and stuff. So for each of these different tools, what angle should they be at? If I need to list the different tools then ask. Otherwise I mostly want to know for the 6 (or so) main types. The more covered the better! The idea is to be sharpened on a bench grinder.

Comment: I expect someone more experienced than myself with turning will be able to go into more detail, but there are multiple factors that determine the optimal angle, such as the type of cut you're making, and the type of task you're performing. For example, when shaping the inside of a deep bowl, the walls of the bowl will limit your range of movement and you will have to grind the end of your tool to a different angle to compensate.

Comment: @Rob Well I am really just getting into the whole wood turning thing. I love doing it and want to (like anything else) keep experimenting and working on my skill. Granted I did not have those factors in mind that is a good point. But ya sorry, I really am not that 'skilled' or anything, just want the best idea if you will.

Comment: @Ljk2000 As Rob had said it depends on a couple variables such as the type of cut you are making but then as well just plain preference. I do not believe there is an "exact" answer to your question. I recommend you just go on Youtube and search something like "lathe tool sharpening". You will find many informative videos, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPhRk8g1iuA), from people with much greater knowledge in this area. Play around with some test pieces and bevels and find out what works best for you in your turning style.

Comment: If you have the tool when it's sharp check where the bevel is and use that as the ref surface.

Comment: I am doing that for now but at some point I might have it off by to much or something. Otherwise I think I am doing that very well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't obsess about the angle, work at sharpening what you have at the moment to a consistent grind and has no multiple facets. Consistency is the key and the wolverine type jigs are great for that. Cap,n Eddie Castalin has lots of good videos and shows how to make in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5i9RDnJHz9g
Don't mark on the jig for each tool because as the are sharpened and get shorter that will change the angle, better to make a story stick for each tool if using the wolverine's cradle. The fingernail grind jig is set to 50mm for everything. Most factory grinds are not good and will need reshaping but that can come a bit later when you can sharpen consistently

You can have the same size gouge with three different grinds depending where about's in the bowl you are cutting. Different woods may also require different angles depending on the wood and density. Brian Havens explains in this video on the skew https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhuEVVSkDtE
Both of these guys have very good videos with lots to learn.

Comment: Cap'n Eddie also sells a Wolverine knock-off called the "Blackhawk."